# Wordpress extracting wp_usermeta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a script that will extract wp_usermeta in a readable layout.

I've got sql like below:

```
select distinct(user_id), meta_value as suburb from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'suburb' order by user_id
```

Now is there a way we can include all other fields aswell using sql query to join the column on the right and make the result coming out in one table so I can use this for csv export?

**UPDATE 25/SEP/2011, 12:34pm:
Doesn't matter guys, I found my answer refer to below sql!!!**

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.user_login,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'title' THEN m.meta_value END) AS title,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value END) AS first_name,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value END) AS last_name,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'suburb' THEN m.meta_value END) AS phone,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'state' THEN m.meta_value END) AS state,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'country' THEN m.meta_value END) AS country,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'postcode' THEN m.meta_value END) AS postcode,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'contact_no' THEN m.meta_value END) AS contact_no,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'email' THEN m.meta_value END) AS email,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'occupation' THEN m.meta_value END) AS occupation,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'workplace' THEN m.meta_value END) AS workplace,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'maternitybg' THEN m.meta_value END) AS maternitybg,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'trainingdate' THEN m.meta_value END) AS trainingdate,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'traininglocation' THEN m.meta_value END) AS traininglocation,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'coltraining' THEN m.meta_value END) AS coltraining,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'trainingyear' THEN m.meta_value END) AS trainingyear,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'coltraining' THEN m.meta_value END) AS coltraining,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'isinstructor' THEN m.meta_value END) AS isinstructor,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'gender' THEN m.meta_value END) AS gender,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'idf_indig_tsi' THEN m.meta_value END) AS idf_indig_tsi,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'idf_ct_ld' THEN m.meta_value END) AS idf_ct_ld,
    MIN(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'comments' THEN m.meta_value END) AS comments

    FROM wp_users u
      LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m ON u.ID = m.user_id
        AND m.meta_key IN ('title', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'suburb', 'state', 'country', 'postcode', 'contact_no', 'email', 'occupation', 'workplace', 'maternitybg', 'trainingdate', 'traininglocation', 'coltraining', 'isinstructor', 'gender', 'idf_indig_tsi', 'idf_ct_ld', 'comments')
    GROUP BY u.ID
```

Hope this helps people looking for this solution!

Comment: Uhm … Do you necessarily require a pure SQL solution? Why not use the WP API instead?

Comment: I wanted to use this as WP API with get_user_meta and generation to csv didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't use SQL directly within WordPress as they offer dozens of functions to do the work for you. Doing so will also keep your code flexible for future upgrades of WordPress.

In your case, you are interested in [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Comment: I have a script that does this so how do I use this with Wordpress API? I have placed it on the template folder but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to create a page and put Template Name comment at the top? Also I tried using csv export function on the actual page itself with get_user_meta but it echos out as a string rather than outputting into csv. Is there a solution for exporting user_meta to csv?